# Ayuda con un problema sobre Arreglos en C#

Tags: c#

tengo un inconveniente con un ejercicio de arreglos en C#, tengo que hacer un Programa que acepta números hasta que el usuario digite 0, muestre el promedio de los números digitados,  diga cuantos números se digitaron, el menor y el mayor del los mismos; He logrado hacer casi todo excepto lo del numero menor, ya que al usuario digitar 0 ese se toma como numero menor, pero debería ser el siguiente mayor que 0. Supongo que una solución seria eliminar el 0 del arreglo antes de buscar el menor, pero despues de buscar no he encontrado como hacerlo.

Ayuda por favor y Gracias de Antemano. 
Este es el código:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Ejercicio4{

    class program{

        public static void Main(string[] args){
            int[] num = new int[10];
            int i, j=0;
            int mayor=0, menor=0, prom=0;
            int top = 1, cont=0;
            int sum=0, cant=-1;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Programa que acepta numeros hasta que el usuario digite 0, muestre el promedio de los numeros digitados,  diga cuantos numeros se digitaron, el menor y el mayor del los mismos.");
            for(i=0; i<num.Length; i++){
                while(top > 0){
                    Console.Write("Digite el numero {0}: ",i+1);
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num[i]);
                    top = num[i];
                    sum = sum + num[i]; //Para sacar el promedio.
                    cant++;
                    i++;
                    cont++;
                    if (top == 0){
                        prom = sum / cant;
                        Console.WriteLine("El promedio de los numeros ingresados es {0}",prom);
                    }
                }
            }
            while(j < 10){
                if(num[j] > mayor){
                    mayor = num[j];
                }
                if(num[j] < menor){
                    menor = num[j];
                }
                j++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Se digitaron {0} numeros", cont-1);
            Console.WriteLine("El mayor de los numeros es: {0}", mayor);
            Console.WriteLine("El menor de los numeros es: {0}", menor);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya encontré una forma de solucionar el problema, tenia  un error de enfoque, después de modificar el código di con la solución (y mucho mas simple), les dejo el código para que lo analicen:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Ejercicio4{

    class program{

        public static void Main(string[] args){
            int i;
            int prom=0;
            int x=0;
            int sum=0, cant=0;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Programa que acepta los numeros que el usuario quiera y: muestre el promedio de los numeros digitados,  diga cuantos numeros se digitaron, el menor y el mayor del los mismos.");
            Console.Write("¿Cuantos numeros desea ingresar? ");
            x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] num = new int[x];          //Aqui se inicializa el array.
            for(i=0; i<num.Length; i++){
                Console.Write("Escriba el numero {0}: ",i+1);
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num[i]);
                sum = sum + num[i];
                cant++;
            }
            prom = sum/cant;
            Console.Write("\n\nSe digitaron {0} numeros", x);
            Console.Write("\n\nEl promedio de los numeros es: {0}", prom);
            Console.Write("\n\nLa mayor venta es: " + num.Max());
            Console.Write("\n\nLa menor venta es: " + num.Min());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Para esta solución has tenido que cambiar los requerimientos, por lo que veo. Si quieres mantener las condiciones originales, existe el comando `break` que te permite salir de un bucle en el momento de invocación

Answer (score 0):

Inicializa menor con el valor máximo que acepta un int `menor = 2147483647` así todos los números ingresados serán (en teoría) menores que 2147483647.